# How to include a command line interface in a gui in python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm currently building an console application in python that does a lot of calculations on input gotten from the user and i've seen several apps that have gui windows but the input is still gotten from the console and this is exactly what i want, i'm currently learning tkinter so i wanted to ask is it possible to do this in tkinter because the tutorial i have on tkinter dosen't talk about including consoles in gui's here is a screenshot of what i mean https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/ZEXe though in the screenshot the command line just prints out what is going on in the program but i want my main application to be in that area, so i can get input from the user and then the results can be printed out on the gui. Answers can also suggest other python gui frameworks. Thanks

Comment: Why not include an `Entry` or `Text` widget for user input in your program?

Comment: i've not tried that, but i basically want the gui to print out the results and contain buttons that would be used to analyze and display the result

Comment: Well, what _have_ you tried? Anything? Creating a GUI with buttons and information is a basic task for `tkinter`. I suggest doing some research into how to construct a `tkinter` app.

Comment: i've seen how they build a few sample apps with tkinter in the tutorial i went throught i even have a small pdf book i use for reference but none of them covers this kind of app, and i'm lost on how to search google properly for it

Comment: I would be surprised if a given `tkinter` tutorial didn't say how to create widgets and display data. Take a look at something like [Effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) and learn how such an app works.

Comment: i'm not trying to display data with the console or use widgets i'm trying to include a full console application with a gui window, doing it with widgets would require me to re-write the whole application

Comment: Five years later (This question was bumped up). I finally understand what you meant @TigerhawkT3 lol. I could've included a text widget and styled it to look like a terminal (i.e black background and white/green text). At the time, I wanted to take a shortcut and just embed a full terminal within my app's window which is actually possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter can accept text inputs and return values based on what is put in. As far as I know there is no actual command line input function. You could always try implementing it yourself. I think this is very customizable so I'm not going to write it myself but these are some of the things u might use:

```
textbox = Entry(root)
textbox.pack()
textbox.config(bg="red") #this would change the background to black. fg for text color
textarea = Text(root) #this creates a big text area
#textbox.get() will return the value of the textbook
```

Also, you could embed a full terminal into a `tkinter` window by using `xterm` (you might need to install it first if it's not natively available on your machine.

```
from tkinter import *

import os

root = Tk()
termf = Frame(root, height=500, width=500)

termf.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
wid = termf.winfo_id()
os.system('xterm -into %d -geometry 100x100 -sb &' % wid)

root.mainloop()
```

This creates a new `tkinter` window (500 x 500) and them embeds an `xterm` window into it (100 x 100)

Comment: This code would not work. Assign the `Entry` widget on one line and then `pack` it on the next, or else you end up assigning `None` - the returned value of `pack()` - to `textbox`, and then you can't do `config()` or `get()` on it, because you don't have an `Entry` widget there.